# Can I use domestic hot water from a gas combination boiler temporarily, while the pressure in the central heating circuit is low?

Tags: boiler

Due to work on the heating pipes, the central heating water pressure is low.
Is there a safe way to use the gas combination boiler (Ferroli Modena 80 E, domestic hot water + central heating) for domestic hot water production (until the end of the work on the heating pipes)?

Currently the low central heating pressure light is blinking (as it should) and the fire does not turn on when hot water taps are opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it is safe, as it's meant to produce domestic hot water in the first place.  The problem is it won't start up because there's no water in it as it all has drained out. You need to put some sort of stops on the inlet and outlet heating pipes and re-pressurize the system before it will produce hot water.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [idea of GdD](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/18438/7480) I put stops on more accessible pipe endings. After this I had to open a valve to restore the pressure in the central heating circuit. Than we had hot water in the taps again.

[image: stop1]
[image: stop2]

Comment: Could you edit this answer in as an **ETA** section in your original post? It's awesome to see how it all worked out, but [consensus](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/686/would-it-be-in-bad-taste-to-post-a-picture-of-a-completed-result-of-a-question-i) is to keep info about the problem in the question and only have answers in the answer section.